# python ADT double-ended queue

Tags: python

Implement the ADT double-ended queue.  This ADT is similar to a queue, but supports functions to add and remove from either end of the queue.

It seems I am struggling with the remove part. This is what I tried:

```
class deq:
def __init__(self):
    self.item = []

def is_empty(self):
    return self.item == None

def size(self):
    return len(self.item)

def add_front(self, item):
    self.item.insert(0,item)

def add_back(self, item):
    selft.item.append(item)

def remove_front(self, item):
    self.item.remove(item)

def remove_back(self, item):
    self.item.pop()
```

The sample screenshot of output:
[This is the sample output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sOSc7.png)

Answer (score 0):

remove_front and remove_back should not consume an item (according to these tests and according to what a queue is).

remove_front always removes the first element, remove_back always removes the last. So these functions don't need to be passed an item.

```
def remove_front(self):
    self.item.pop(0)

def remove_back(self):
    self.item.pop()
```

You could have easily debugged this yourself in 2 seconds by looking at why the test was failing: "missing 1 positional argument". This means that the automated test is calling your function with one fewer argument than your function expected.

Answer (score -2):

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    int choice;

    while (true) {
        // Displaying the menu options
        std::cout << "Menu Options:\n";
        std::cout << "1. Option 1\n";
        std::cout << "2. Option 2\n";
        std::cout << "3. Option 3\n";
        std::cout << "4. Option 4\n";
        std::cout << "5. Exit\n";
        std::cout << "Enter your choice: ";
        std::cin >> choice;

        switch (choice) {
            case 1:
                std::cout << "You selected Option 1.\n";
                // Perform actions for Option 1
                break;
            case 2:
                std::cout << "You selected Option 2.\n";
                // Perform actions for Option 2
                break;
            case 3:
                std::cout << "You selected Option 3.\n";
                // Perform actions for Option 3
                break;
            case 4:
                std::cout << "You selected Option 4.\n";
                // Perform actions for Option 4
                break;
            case 5:
                std::cout << "Exiting the program. Goodbye!\n";
                return 0;
            default:
                std::cout << "Invalid choice. Please try again.\n";
                break;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Avoid code only answer and provide an explanation;